# Webpack error: “You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type”

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I get the following error "**You may need appropriate loader to handle this file type**" while using Webpack to compile ES6 and JSX files.

Terminal ERROR:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react';
| import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

**webpack.config.js** looks like this,

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 2525
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015','react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**main.js** file contains,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <h1>Title text</h1>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

**package.json** looks like this,

```
{
  "name": "react-webpack-es6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

Let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: try **test: /\.jsx$/** instead of **test: /\.js$/** inside loaders array of webpack config

Comment: @KishoreBarik As mentioned below, it was due to the **test**, it shouldn't be wrapped inside quotes. Thanks for prompt response :)

Comment: oh yes, it was quotes, though I copied correct text from my config, I didn't notice the quotes :P :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `webpack.config.js`, the `test` property in `module.loaders` should be a regular expression, not a string.

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: '/\.js$/',
```

change this `'/\.js$/'` to this `/\.js$/`

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
```

Know more at [webpack/module-loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders)

Comment: @WitVault asked about hot-reloading in the previous answer's comments. Here's my take:  Use something like Redux and Webpack hot module replacement. Preserving state in React components during reloading is hard. Know more at [Hot Reloading in React](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/hot-reloading-in-react-1140438583bf#.kkr25hogs). The solution will end up being keep state somewhere that will not reloaded (Redux store, or localstorage).

Comment: Thank god I found this. I would have spent 30 minutes for no reason debugging something stupid like this.